# How to fix and repeat a content at bottom of every page when I print at Chrome and IE

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqe4p.jpg)

I want to fix and repeat a blue part at bottom of every page when I print at Chrome and IE. I tried `@page {@bottom-center {...}}` and `display:fixed; bottom:0;`. But It's not working. Is there any other way?

Comment: use flexbox layout or grid layout for fixing the container at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a nice layout to the pages you need to use either a [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout or [`grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) layout.

The flexbox layout of your case is given below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  /*important*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```